# can't upload file using ftplib over ssh-tunnel

Tags: python, ftp, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to upload a file using `ftplib` over an sshtunnel. I can login successfully to the remote end ftp server over this tunnel, but the program times out when trying to send the file.

```
import paramiko
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
from ftplib import FTP

USER               = ["userSSH","passSSH"]
SSHPORT            = 22
SSHIP              = "A.B.C.D"
ROUTER_FTP_PORT    = 21
REMOTE_FTP         = "W.X.Y.Z"

fserver = SSHTunnelForwarder( (SSHIP, SSHPORT), 
    ssh_username        = USER[0], 
    ssh_password        = USER[1], 
    remote_bind_address = (REMOTE_FTP, ROUTER_FTP_PORT), )

fserver.start()
fport = fserver.local_bind_port

ftp = FTP()
ftp.connect("127.0.0.1",fport)
ftp.login("ftpUser","ftpPass")
file = open('lucas.cfg','rb')
ftp.storbinary('STOR lucas.cfg',file)
file.close()
```

I can certanly connect and login:

```
In [8]: ftp.connect("127.0.0.1",fport)
Out[8]: '220 FTP server ready'

In [9]: ftp.login("ftpUser","ftpPass")
Out[9]: '230 User logged in'
```

... but a time out rises when trying to upload the file ...

```
In [19]: ftp.storbinary('STOR lucas.cfg',file)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-0af0cb3b5ebf> in <module>()
----> 1 ftp.storbinary('STOR lucas.cfg',file)

/usr/lib/python3.6/ftplib.py in storbinary(self, cmd, fp, blocksize, callback, rest)
    502         """
    503         self.voidcmd('TYPE I')
--> 504         with self.transfercmd(cmd, rest) as conn:
    505             while 1:
    506                 buf = fp.read(blocksize)

/usr/lib/python3.6/ftplib.py in transfercmd(self, cmd, rest)
    397     def transfercmd(self, cmd, rest=None):
    398         """Like ntransfercmd() but returns only the socket."""
--> 399         return self.ntransfercmd(cmd, rest)[0]
    400 
    401     def login(self, user = '', passwd = '', acct = ''):

/usr/lib/python3.6/ftplib.py in ntransfercmd(self, cmd, rest)
    359             host, port = self.makepasv()
    360             conn = socket.create_connection((host, port), self.timeout,
--> 361                                             source_address=self.source_address)
    362             try:
    363                 if rest is not None:

/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address)
    722 
    723     if err is not None:
--> 724         raise err
    725     else:
    726         raise error("getaddrinfo returns an empty list")

/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address)
    711             if source_address:
    712                 sock.bind(source_address)
--> 713             sock.connect(sa)
    714             # Break explicitly a reference cycle
    715             err = None

TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

any hint?

thanks!

Comment: are you sure that you have connection to A.B.C.D : 21 ??? ...first try from where is locate your script by console telnet A.B.C.D  21

Comment: yes, I'm sure. A.B.C.D is the SSH server that I use as bypass towardes the remote ftp server. On the other hand, I can certainly login, as shown above: `Out[9]: '230 User logged in'` ... this means that the tunnel towards port 21 on `W.X.Y.Z ` is working but for some reason I cannot `put` a file ...

Comment: You didn't tell us anything about your tunnel. Did you forward the data ports? + Can you even transfer a file over the tunnel using any existing FTP client?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, I've tried using both `passive` and `active` methods with FTP and none of those worked over SSH. The truth is the data port is not being tunneled. In order to solve this (and to avoid creating a second tunnel for the data channel) I used sftp instead. I'll show this on the answer. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the thing is I was missing tunneling the data port of FTP. In order to avoid creating a second tunnel, I just used sftp instead.

```
server = SSHTunnelForwarder( (SSHIP, SSHPORT), 
    ssh_username        = USER[0], 
    ssh_password        = USER[1], 
    remote_bind_address = (REMOTE_SFTP, ROUTER_SFTP_PORT), )

server.start()
sftpPort = server.local_bind_port

transport = paramiko.Transport(("127.0.0.1",sftpPort))
transport.connect(None,username,password)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
sftp.put(fileLocal,fileRemote)
```

With the previous I can upload a file to a remote SFTP server over an SSH tunnel. Yes, is not FTP, but it worked for me.

If FTP is the only possible way, then a second ssh tunnel for the data channel will be needed.